# Custom tab names (for 'index' files) in Sublime text

Tags: javascript, sublimetext3

#### The Question:

Is there a way to configure Sublime Text (3) so it looks back to its' parent folder to get the name which appears in the Tab only IF the current file name is say `index.js`?

#### The problem

Most Javascript projects are organised where files sit within folders (eg `Component1/index.js`, `Component2/index.js`).

Therefore, with several components open, Sublime tabs area all called `index.js`- or they get the file path- making it hard to quickly switch between.

Comment: Sorry to dig this up, but did you perhaps manage to solve this? I'm having a lot of duplicate index.js, server.js, etc. and have yet to find a way to differentiate them quickly, using the folder's name would be perfect for me.